# A problem on Demailly's proof of finiteness theorem of elliptic differential operator

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I am reading Demailly's notes on pseudodifferential operators on manifolds. And I cannot understand a statement he had made when he tried to prove that the image of an elliptic differential operator is closed.

Here is part of his original proof:
He claims that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a finite number of elements $v_{1},...,v_{N}\in W^{s+\delta}(M)$, $N=N(\epsilon)$, such that $$
||u||_{0}\leq\epsilon||u||_{s+\delta}+\sum_{j=1}^{N}|\langle u,v_{j}\rangle_{0}|
$$
Here $W^{i}$s are the Sobolev spaces of order $i$ whoes norms are subscribed with the corresponding index $i$. And $\langle.,.\rangle$ is the inner product in the Hilbert space $W^{0}=L^{2}$.
To prove the statement, Demailly constructed a family of sets:$$
K_{(v_{j})}=\{u\in W^{s+\delta};\epsilon||u||_{s+\delta}+\sum_{j=1}^{N}|\langle u,v_{j}\rangle_{0}|\leq1\}
$$
that are relatively compact in $W^{0}$ (this is true by Rellich's embedding lemma)and $\bigcap_{(v_{j})} K_{(v_{j})}={0}$(if the intersection was taken among arbitrary indexes ($v_{i}$), then it is clearly true). Then he concluded that:
there is a finite sequence $(v_{j})$ such that $K_{(v_{j})}$ is contained in the unit ball of $W^{0}$.

This statement is what I am confused with. Indeed I have proved that if for an increasing sequence of $(v_{j})$ we have $\bigcap_{(v_{j})}K_{(v_{j})}=\{0\}$, then his statement is true. But the main issue here is that (in my opinion)the intersection should be taken among uncountably many indexes $(v_{j})$ to garantee it shrinking to $\{0\}$.

Comment: There must be something else going on, because what you've written is just not at all true.  For example, even in $X = \mathbb{R}$ you can take $K_1 = [0, 2]$ and $K_2 = [-2, 0]$; neither in contained in the unit ball, both are compact, and $K_1 \cap K_2 = \{0\}$.

Comment: @Chirs Eagle I have provided the details of his proof.

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question fully, but if I did, maybe this helps: if you have an (not necessarily increasing) sequence $(v_j)_1, (v_j)_2,\dots$, you can make it increasing by considering a new sequence $(\nu_j)_2 =(v_j)_1 \cup (v_j)_2 $, since, in your case (at least in my vision), $K_{(\nu_j)_2}\subseteq K_{(v_j)_1} \cap K_{ \cup (v_j)_2}$. I did with the first two elements of the sequence, but it is easily generalized to the k-th element

Comment: @Burno The problem is it may not be a sequence, there are uncountably many $(v_{j})$, if we only pick a sequence, the intersection may not be 0.